# CMake configure_file fails if not run by output file owner

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake 3.27.4 on Ubuntu 20.04. We have a cloud build system which will mount my code and run a build, in addition to being able to run builds locally. I have my shared directory setup with setguid, so that any files created by the cloud build will have a consistent group ownership, and my user is in that group with r/w permissions.

The issue: After running a cloud build, a file generated by `configure_file` has been created with a different user (cloud build doesn't run as me). When I then try to run a local build, that `configure_file` step fails with output:

```
CMake Error at buildTools/configPaths.cmake:25 (configure_file):
  Operation not permitted
```

If I change file ownership back to my local user, the error goes away.

I've confirmed that I can read/write the file directly when the cloud build user owns it (no issues with permissions when not running through CMake).

If I delete the file and re-run locally, it's created with my user and the expected group (no uid switching somewhere in our build).

It's an easy enough fix each time, but I wanted to know if there's a way to allow CMake overwrite the configure_file output when CMake is invoked by a user that only has group ownership (r/w) of the output file.